# How to bind key from tmux to cmd on osx and iterm?

Tags: macos, tmux, superuser

Recently I am converting from screen to tmux. but I need a way to bind cmd key - left/right for move between windows. I have my screen setup like this

```
bindkey "^[[C" next # bind to cmd+->, the escape sequence is binded in iterm2
bindkey "^[[D" prev # bind to cmd+<-
```

in iterms i just set the escape sequence to cmd+left/right keys. but can’t figure out how to bind escape sequence to next/right in tmux
btw, bind-key -n appears in many configs, wonder what ‘-n’ mean?

Comment: This would be better for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).